# How to work out resistance of milli-ohm resistors?

Tags: resistors

I have a dilemma. The schematics for a development board I am using specifies that it uses 20 milli-ohm resistors for current sensing (7 current sense channels). However, by calibration (using low burden voltage fluke ammeter), I have "calculated" that the resistance is 27 milli ohms (plotted around 6 operating points, fitted a linear curve to it, gradient of V-I graph is 27.004 with R^2 = 0.9996).

So I am now confused. Is it really 27 milliohms or 20 milliohms? These are 0603 resistors, and common multimeters don't range down to the milliohms. :(

Comment: What is the ammeter accuracy in the 20mΩ range?

Comment: In light of a comment on ThomasO's answer, I think you should explain exactly how you are measuring these values.

Answer (score 6):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelvin_bridge

"A Kelvin bridge (also called a Kelvin double bridge and in some countries a Thomson bridge) is a measuring instrument invented by William Thomson, 1st Baron Kelvin. It is used to measure an unknown electrical resistance below 1 Ω."

Answer (score 3):

What you are probably experiencing is contact resistance. The resistance of your ammeter, for example, is going to be on the order of 10 milliohms, which would account for your 7 milliohm extra measurement (including a reasonable tolerance in other components.)

You can measure the resistance of a very low ohm resistor by using 4-wire measurement. Expensive bench multimeters support this.

However... I suspect you have only 2-wire measurement on low cost meters. So there is another way to do it. It however requires you to have two multimeters; it is not possible to use one, unfortunately, because removing one from the circuit will change the result. However, even cheap $5 meters will be fine for decent 1% measurement.

You will need a 5V or so power supply, a 100 ohm 5% resistor, your test resistor and two multimeters.

Here's how to do it: Place the 100 ohm resistor in series with the test resistor and apply power using the power supply. The output voltage is not critical, but don't go too high. Connect a multimeter as an ammeter in series with the resistor or supply. Then, connect one of the multimeters as a voltmeter right across the resistor - you want to be right up to the edges of the resistor's casing, just touching the terminals, to get the most accurate reading, as any resistance of the leads will affect the result. Then, use Ohm's law to solve for R given V and I. (Hint: R = V / I.) What you've effectively done is cancelled out the series resistance of the ammeter, power supply, wires and 100 ohm resistor by measuring the voltage drop across the resistor directly.

Comment: It looks like this is what cksa361 is already doing. This doesn't eliminate contact resistance.

Comment: @tyblu, I'm not sure. They seem to be using an ammeter and a fixed voltage, not measuring the voltage across the resistor directly, which is pretty much identical to 2-wire measurement, and includes the ~10mOhm shunt of the meter.

Comment: sorry gtg lunch, but i put different CPU loads on the dev board... and measured the current via the input jack...against the measured current via the I2C Current monitor

Comment: @cksa361 How accurate is that I2C current monitor and does it exclude or include the current consumed in the monitor?